# who to write Urdu in text box in vb.net wpf form

Tags: sql, wpf, vb.net

who to write Urdu in text box in vb.net wpf form I try this below code but bellow underline occur
what I am doing wrong?
 " reference to non shared members InputLanguageManager.CurrentInputLanguage"

```
Private Sub urdu_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As TextChangedEventArgs) Handles urdu.GotFocus
    InputLanguageManager.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLanguageManager.InstalledInputLanguages(2)
    Dim variable As String = urdu.Text
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that Urdu is already installed on your system. You can try like this:

```
Public Sub urdu_GotFocus(ByVal InputLang As InputLanguage)
   If InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages.IndexOf(InputLang) = -1 Then
        Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException()
   End If
    InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = InputLang
End Sub
```

Note that [InputLanguage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.inputlanguage.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) is present in `System.Windows.Forms` namespace and in   `System.Windows.Forms.dll` assembly.

You can also refer MSDN blog for [Changing the input language in a textbox at runtime](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsarabic/archive/2007/04/29/changing-the-input-language-in-a-textbox-at-runtime.aspx)

Comment: I Imports System.Windows.Forms it also underline and shows error

Comment: @SoniaRehman:- What is the exact error which you are getting?

Comment: Warning 1 Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'System.Windows.Forms' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases. C:\Users\atk\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\insert.xaml.vb 1 9 WpfApplication1

Comment: @SoniaRehman:- Have you added the reference to the dll `System.Windows.Forms.dll` in your project? Also refer this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms234657.aspx

Comment: NOTHING HAPPEN I TRY YOUR ABOVE CODE ALSO ERROR REMOVED BUT TEXT BOX NOT GOING TO SHOW URDU